# What data structure is used to implement pattern match?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

In the book "Programming Elixir", the author states that "Even if you have thousands of clauses, pattern matching used in this way is fast. Matching a map or struct is O(log n).".

I wonder what data structure is used to implement pattern match in Elixir such that the time complexity if O(log n).

Is it some kind of tree structure?

Comment: I suppose it is the Kernel https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pattern matching - implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586362/pattern-matching-implementation)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Thanks for finding a related question. But I think they are not identical, Erlang and Elixir are not the same language.

Comment: Elixir delegates to Erlang for pattern matching. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elixir delegates to Erlang's pattern matching.

Looking through Elixir's source code, written in Erlang, here is the code that seems to be handling matching:

[elixir_clauses.erl](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/5984c6cc29a41d5bc78d49427730c8786d75e2c9/lib/elixir/src/elixir_clauses.erl#L26):

```
match(Fun, Expr, #{current_vars := Current, unused_vars := {_, Counter} = Unused} = AfterE, BeforeE) ->
  #{
    context := Context,
    prematch_vars := Prematch,
    current_vars := {Read, _}
  } = BeforeE,

  CallE = BeforeE#{
    context := match,
    prematch_vars := {Read, Counter},
    current_vars := Current,
    unused_vars := Unused
  },

  {EExpr, #{current_vars := NewCurrent, unused_vars := NewUnused}} = Fun(Expr, CallE),

  EndE = AfterE#{
    context := Context,
    prematch_vars := Prematch,
    current_vars := NewCurrent,
    unused_vars := NewUnused
  },

  {EExpr, EndE}.
```

This is Erlang code, so here Elixir is delegating to [Erlang's `=` operator](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#match). As this is the case, Robert Virding (the author of Erlang's pattern matching code)'s answer to [this related Erlang question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642896/1225617) is useful:

> A very good description of compiling pattern matching is given in "The
> implementation of functional programming languages" by Simon Peyton
> Jones. It is a bit old but a very good book. It also contains, amongst
> other things, a description of compiling list comprehensions.
>
> The Erlang compiler uses both of these algorithms from the book.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of pattern matching differs across functional languages but in most of the cases it boils down to decision trees.

Luc Maranget [paper](http://pauillac.inria.fr/%7Emaranget/papers/ml05e-maranget.pdf) "Compiling Pattern Matching to Good Decision Trees" gives a pretty good in depth description of how pattern matching can be implemented into decision trees.

Another very good resource in merit is the [book](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/1096899) "The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages" by Simon Peyton Jones.

Comment: Joe said a lot in his talks that the pattern matching is implemented based on the one in prolog.

Comment: Robert Virding, who wrote Erlang's pattern matching, which Elixir uses, [states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586362/pattern-matching-implementation#comment992425_642896) that Erlang uses the algorithms from the SPJ book.